# Как отредактировать файл json с помощью gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

У меня есть файл json который мне надо как-то отредактировать. Проблема в том что я редактирую файл тем для мессенджера и он всегда отличается, в одном больше значений в другом меньше.
Мне надо не заново написать файл, а просто например поменять title и не трогать другое например night (он не всегда есть).
Возможно ли это?

```
{
  "author" : "TTTEditor",
  "colors" : {
    "accent" : "#1",
    "unreadText" : "#ffffff"
  },
  "night" : true,
  "title" : "Dark-Grey",
  "version" : 1
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: перегоните json в объект. отредактируйте объект. перегоните объект в json. перезапишите файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Парсим json из файла с помощью [JsonParser](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html) библиотеки Gson:

```java
JsonObject jsonObject;
try (Reader reader = new FileReader("input.json")) {
    jsonObject = JsonParser.parseReader(reader).getAsJsonObject();
}
```

Меняем поле `title` на новое значение:

```java
jsonObject.add("title", new JsonPrimitive("New Title"));
```

Пишем json в файл:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
try (Writer writer = new FileWriter("output.json")) {
    gson.toJson(jsonObject, writer);
}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, у меня такая же проблема. Можно поинтересоваться, а если ключ находится в объекте (например ```{"Global":{"UITheme": "Default"}}```, как его редактировать?

Comment: Чтобы поменять поле `UITheme`, вторым шагом выполните этот код: `jsonObject.get("Global").getAsJsonObject().add("UITheme", new JsonPrimitive("New Theme"));`