# Как сделать, чтобы GSON, после вызова toJson, не заменял исходное содержимое файла, а лишь заменял значения?

Tags: java, json, gson

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

В переменную `json` я сначала помещаю JSON-файл, отображаю:

```
Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, json, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

всё норм, JSON весь. А после метода `toJson` в `json` находится только то, что я хотел изменить:

```
{"Global":{"UITheme":"Default"}}
```

Остальная часть JSON пропала. Как настроить, чтобы GSON только заменял значения нужных ключей?

### P.S.

Ответ ниже помог, НО: он один раз срабатывает, а далее выдаёт ошибку `Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at...`

```
JsonElement jsonE = JsonParser.parseString(json);
            JsonElement global = jsonE.getAsJsonObject().get("Global");
            global.getAsJsonObject().add("UITheme", new JsonPrimitive(UITheme));
            json = new Gson().toJson(jsonE);
```

Кстати, после выполнения, форматирование не сохраняется (удаляются пробелы и табуляция).

Как решить?

```
(кусочек)
{
"Global": {
        "Locale": "Auto",
        "UITheme": "Space",
        "OperReq": "Checkbox"
    }
}
```

Текст ошибки:

```
E/mate.files: [qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: mate.files, PID: 1008
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1704 path $
        at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parseReader(JsonParser.java:74)
        at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parseString(JsonParser.java:50)
        at mate.files.Welcome$2.onCheckedChanged(Welcome.java:273)
        at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:190)
        at android.widget.RadioGroup.access$600(RadioGroup.java:57)
        at android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:375)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:179)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:132)
        at android.widget.RadioButton.toggle(RadioButton.java:76)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:137)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6631)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:790)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26187)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1704 path $
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1607)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1414)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:552)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:435)
        at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parseReader(JsonParser.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parseString(JsonParser.java:50) 
        at mate.files.Welcome$2.onCheckedChanged(Welcome.java:273) 
        at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:190) 
        at android.widget.RadioGroup.access$600(RadioGroup.java:57) 
        at android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:375) 
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:179) 
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:132) 
        at android.widget.RadioButton.toggle(RadioButton.java:76) 
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:137) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6631) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:790) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26187) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Comment: Кажется немного не хватает кода в вопросе. например модели в которую вы JSON парсите и самого JSON. По сути вопроса - можно предположить что вам надо удалить `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отредактировать файл json с помощью gson?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1454368/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-json-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-gson)

Comment: Из вопроса не совсем ясно, вы показываете содержимое Json, которое было до преобразования или после? Приведите Json до и после в вопросе. Посмотрите разницу, совпадает ли все остальное в Json содержимом?

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, у вас есть json-файл `input.json` со следующим содержимым:

```json
{"Global":{"Locale":"Auto","UITheme":"Default"}}
```

Парсим json из файла с помощью [JsonParser](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html) библиотеки Gson:

```java
JsonElement json;
try (Reader reader = new FileReader("input.json")) {
    json = JsonParser.parseReader(reader);
}
```

Достаем объект `Global` и меняем в нем значение `UITheme` на новое:

```java
JsonElement global = json.getAsJsonObject().get("Global");
global.getAsJsonObject().add("UITheme", new JsonPrimitive("New Theme"));
```

Пишем json в файл:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
try (Writer writer = new FileWriter("output.json")) {
    gson.toJson(json, writer);
}
```

На выходе получим файл `output.json`:

```json
{"Global":{"Locale":"Auto","UITheme":"New Theme"}}
```

Comment: А вот с этим что делать? ```Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON``` Я попытался как-то что-то сделать, но ничего не работает

Comment: У вас в вопросе не представлен исходный json, поэтому я точно не могу сказать. У вас проблема с json, он имеет не совсем верный формат. Обновите вопрос, либо создайте [новый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Приложите исходный json и полный текст ошибки вместе со стектрейсом.

Comment: Я обновил вопрос

Comment: Скорей всего проблема в той части json, которую вы не показываете в вопросе. Создайте [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), чтобы можно было воспроизвести вашу проблему.

Comment: Чтобы сохранить json в форматированном виде, нужно добавить `setPrettyPrinting()`, я обновил ответ.

Comment: Я  проверял свой JSON на онлайн-сервисах, ошибок в нём нет. Тем более, оно первый раз нормально срабатывает, а потом, когда я пытаюсь снова работать с JSON, оно выдаёт ошибку. Как будто сам GSON мой файл карёжит.

Comment: Полный JSON: https://mega.nz/file/C5QUxTIS#t5jhuLbCQ6ThQrlGLQ4_cBiibxLethQFVl7a8iZnkaY

Comment: После работы GSON на выходе даёт JSON-строку, и отказывается затем её парсить, выдавая ошибку. https://mega.nz/file/rhhhGRyA#SIN-b4yOcyn5X-uy28XizQpCMs_K0iJ3uOp-EESI2pE

Comment: Я пробовал вызывать ```setPrettyPrinting``` у GsonBuilder, но оно не работало

Comment: А теперь он пишет ошибку: ```End of input at line 82 column 4 path $.BarsAndMenus.Layout1BottomContent[6]``` при втором срабатывании

Comment: В ошибке написано, что проблема в Json в строке 1 в символе номер 1704, я не знаю, что у вас там, поэтому не смогу ответить на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Там... конец строчки. Что ему не нравится?